# What is the difference between different openerp launchpad repositories?

Tags: odoo, repository, launchpad

Can anyone tell me the difference between these repositories

lp:openobject-addons

lp:openobject-addons/extra-trunk

lp:~openerp-community/openobject-addons/trunk-addons-community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openobject-addons` contains the "certified" addons, maintained by OpenERP SA.

`extra-trunk` contains 3rd party addons. It was split from `openobject-addons` in 2008. The quality of the addons in there varies greatly and some of the addons are not maintained at all, but a lot of them are useful. To contribute to that branch, you need to do a merge proposal and get it approved by OpenERP SA.

`trunk-addons-community` seems to be a recent branch containing new addons. You can contribute to it if you are a member of the openerp-community team.

The current trend is to move the most useful addons from `extra-trunk` to new branches with a smaller focus to ease maintainance. You can browse the latest addons at [apps.openerp.com](http://apps.openerp.com/), and you can also [register your own addons](http://apps.openerp.com/send_branch/).

Answer (score 0):

1. **lp:openobject-addons** : Is official Addons Repository of the OpenERP, It contains mostly Certified module iwth regular update and long term support.
2. **lp:openobject-addons/extra-trunk** : Is trunk forked branch way back. It contains modules from OpenERP non certified modules as well as OpenERP partner are allowed  to commit in it. But The quality of the module depends on choice of the Contributor. It needs less rights than committing in addons.
3. **lp:~openerp-community/openobject-addons/trunk-addons-community** : This is purely a Community branch. If you are part of OpenERP Community Team you can play with the way you want.

Thank you